# How I can set auto height to svg element?

Tags: javascript, html, css, svg

I have svg element and 4 rect in it.

```
<svg class="quarterly-graph">
    <rect y="0" width="100%" height="5" transform="translate(0,0)" style="fill: #ffffff;"></rect>
    <rect y="5" width="100%" height="90" transform="translate(0,0)" style="fill: #e7f0f5;"></rect>
    <rect y="95" width="100%" height="5" transform="translate(0,0)" style="fill: #ffffff;"></rect>
    <rect y="100" width="100%" height="5" transform="translate(0,0)" style="fill: #e7f0f5;"></rect>
</svg>
```

I have simple css for it:

```
.quarterly-graph {
    height : auto;
    border: 1px #000000 solid;
}
```

How I can set svg height equal height of 4 rects?

jsfiddle example: http://jsfiddle.net/CpZQY/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AFAIK you cannot do this with pure CSS. Your SVG does not specify all required attributes and thus default sizes will be used instead. You will have to specify the viewport/size at the SVG element. This should be no problem, because you have hard coded values in the `rect`s, too. If  you add a `width="105px"` to your svg element you do not need the CSS height directive anymore.

Comment: Unfortunately, I have many dynamic generated rects with different sizes

Comment: At the time you generate them dynamically you can update the height property - like `height = Math.max(height, rect.x + rect.height)` - if the shapes are more complex using Javascript's getBBox method might prove useful.